# How can I send to json data for my controller in ajax mvc?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

My problem: I'm sending JSON data, but my JSON data is going "null"? I don't understand why it's going null.

I read to all documentation but I am new for jquery.
What am I missing? 
I need to send JSON data for my controller.

**Index.cshtml:**

```js
var UserData = {
    "CustomerID": "99999",
    "CustomerCode": "0",
    "UserID":"127",
    "StartDate": "02/09/2019",
    "FinishDate": "03/08/2020",
    "SuccesID": "1",
    "Cash": "1",
    "ProblemID": "1",
    "PageNo":"1",
    "DataNo":"1"
};
var userDataJson = JSON.stringify(UserData);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Problems/Search",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: userDataJson,
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    },
    error: function (err) {
        alert("search error");
    }
});
```

**Model:**

```cs
public class ProblemsInput
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string FinishDate { get; set; }
    public string SuccesID { get; set; }
    public string Cash { get; set; }
    public string ProblemID { get; set; }
    public string PageNo { get; set; }
    public string DataNo { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search(ProblemsInput problemsinput)
{
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just apply [`FromBody`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.frombodyattribute) attribute to the `problemsinput` parameter:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Search([FromBody]ProblemsInput problemsinput) 
{ 
    return View(); 
}
```

Comment: Oh, @FurkanYılmaz, if you are using ASP.NET *Core*, then you are right when use `JSON.stringify`. But you forget to add `FromBody` attribute, that force to find value within request body.

Answer (score 0):

Dude. This problem is your UserData. Try this code:

```
var problemsinput= {
    CustomerID: '99999',
    CustomerCode: '0',
    UserID:'127',
    StartDate: '02/09/2019',
    FinishDate: '03/08/2020',
    SuccesID: '1',
    Cash: '1',
    ProblemID: '1',
    PageNo: '1',
    DataNo: '1',
};

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/Problems/Search",
     contentType: "application/json",
     data: {problemsinput},
     success: function (msg) {
         console.log(msg);
     },
     error: function (err) {
         alert("search error");
     }
});
```

If this doesnt work. Use [FromBody] attribute in Controller an try again. I hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add

```
 data: JSON.stringify({"problemsinput":userDataJson}),
```

instead of `data: userDataJson,`
This will solve the problem.

Ajax call will be

```
var userDataJson = JSON.stringify(UserData);
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/Problems/Search",
         contentType: "application/json",
         data: JSON.stringify({"problemsinput":userDataJson}),
         success: function (msg) {
             console.log(msg);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("search error");
        }
    });
```